# Try/catch exceptions in Red language

Tags: exception, rebol, red

I have a small GUI application with a text-field and a button. The button triggers a function which tries to read a number from text-field. An exception is raised if the text-field is blank or has non-numeric text.

I am trying to catch error if text-field does not have a value or has text value rather than a valid number:

```
calc: does [
    try [x: to integer! num_field/text]
    catch [ print "Could not get number"]
    print "Number read"
]
```

Following also does not work:

```
calc: does [
    try [x: to integer! num_field/text]
    throw 123
    print "Number read"
]
catch 123 [ print "Could not get number"]
```

I am not sure how to use try, throw and catch here. I tried to check section 10 of http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs.html but could not really understand.

How can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRY` will still pass an error if one is generated, however it isn't triggered unless it's the last value evaluated.

You could use the following:

```
calc: does [
    case [
        error? value: try [
            to integer! num_field/text
        ][
            ... do error handling ...
            probe make map! body-of :value
        ]

        integer? value [
            ... do successful thing ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

Aside from `TRY`, there is also `ATTEMPT` which will just return `NONE` if an error occurs. Unlike `TRY`, you can't analyze the error object.

```
attempt [to integer! "Foo"]
```

`CATCH` and `THROW` are more flow control functions in Rebol/Red than error handlers, they break out of however many stack levels they cross:

```
catch [
    repeat x 10 [
        probe x
        if x = 3 [throw x]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can we use `if` instead of `case` if we do not need successful part (`integer? value ...`)?

Comment: @rnso Yep. `case` is like a super-`if`.
`if error? foo: try [to integer! "Foo"][... your error handler here ...]`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `attempt` to catch eventual conversion errors and test the resulting value:

```
calc: does [
    either integer? x: attempt [to-integer num_field/text][
        print "Number read"
    ][
        print "Could not get number"
    ]
]
```

However, there is an even simpler option in this specific case:

```
calc: does [
    either integer? x: num_field/data [
        print "Number read"
    ][
        print "Could not get number"
    ]
]
```

The `/data` facet contains a converted version of `/text` already, or `none` if no conversion is possible, so you can just read/write that facet for numerical values to be displayed in `text` or `field` faces.

> I tried to check section 10 of http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs.html but could not really understand.

That documentation is for Red/System, the system programming DSL embedded in Red. The Red language documentation is at http://docs.red-lang.org (still under heavy work).